# Limit problem help

Tags: limits

I have never encounter "proof" questions before in my career, but this question in textbook troubled me and I have totally no clue where to start.

Prove that the limit
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2}
=& \lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2}\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
=& \lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{1^2-\left(1-x^2\right)}{x^2\left(1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)}\\
=& \lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{x^2}{x^2\left(1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)}\\
=& \lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
=& \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-0^2}}\\
=& \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Multiply by the conjugate of the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

L'Hôpital's rule to the rescue:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2} =\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{d/dx(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})}{d/dx(x^2)} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Let $x:=0$

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-0^2}}=\frac{1}{2}$$